# Добавление слушателя ActionListener в цикле Java

Tags: java

Добрый день.

Вопрос такой: после запуска ввожу в jtf текст, получаю исключение

> `.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10`

Почему не работает? И как исправить?

```
void iter() {
    jtfAnswer = new JTextField[10];
    for(  j=0; j < jtfAnswer.length; j++) {
        jtfAnswer[j] = new JTextField(15);

        jtfAnswer[j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if(jtfAnswer[j].getText().equals(jlab1.getText()))
                    jlab2.setText("try");
                else
                    jlab2.setText("false");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: <code>for(  j=0; j <= jtfAnswer.length; j++)</code>  
а вообще это в корне неправильно. делайте так как вам посоветовали @Nofate

Answer (score 2):

После того как ваш цикл исполняется, значение `j` равно `10`.

Вы вводите значение в текстовое поле и попадаете в обработчик события, в котором обращаетесь к элементу массива. С каким индексом? `10`.

Обращайтесь к объекту инициировавшему событие через `ae.getSource()`.